# How can I connect separated date in python

Tags: python, dataframe, date, concatenation

As you can see in the image, one `CAR_ID` has two different Start date and End date. I'd like to concatenate/connect the first `END_DT` and the second `ST_DT`.
For example,

Output :

```
CAR_ID          BILG_ST_DT     BILG_END_DT
HD04010300002    20150919        20180628
HD01010300003    20150918        20190917
```

Input :

[image: Input]

Comment: How do you want it concatenated?  Show us an example of what you want it to look like.

Comment: Are the date ranges for one `CAR_ID` always exactly one day apart? If so, you could just find the minimum start date and the maximum end date for each group of rows (grouped by `CAR_ID`).

Comment: @DavidCollins I think the image is the input data and the code block is the desired output.

Comment: The image is the input data, the code block is the output data. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

can you try the following:

```
df[['BILG_ST_DT', 'BILG_END_DT']] = df[['BILG_ST_DT', 'BILG_END_DT']].apply(pd.to_datetime, format='%Y%m%d')
df.groupby(by=['CAR_ID']).agg({'BILG_ST_DT': 'min', 'BILG_END_DT': 'max'})
```